# MSB4018 The "RazorGenerate" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-core

I have updated my visual studio 2019 to latest version with .net 5
after that any project with .net core 2.2 gives this error
Error   MSB4018 The "RazorGenerate" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: DOTNET_HOST_PATH is not set
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.DotNetToolTask.get_DotNetPath()

**After one day try to run the project i find out**
that you have to install from huget
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="2.2.0"
to solve the problem

Comment: It sounds like you encountered a problem, and then solved your problem. It's fine to post a question and then answer it. But you should post your answer as an answer, not embed it into your question. That way, your question will show up as answered for people struggling with a similar problem.

Answer (score 12):

After one day try to run the project i find out that you have to install from nuget PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="2.2.0" to solve the problem

Comment: worked perfect, for me was v3.x to solve for asp.net core 3.x projects

Answer (score 1):

This is something issue with VS. for me I have added 'DOTNET_HOST_PATH' path with
%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\dotnet.exe . and restarted . problem solevd